# out-of-range error when subseting values from an xts object in R

Tags: r, subset, xts

I would like to subset dates from an xts object based on logical values in another xts object, but R returns an out-of-range error despite having in-range values.

For example I would like to filter dates and prices where RSI is above 60.

```
> strength <- RSI(d, 14)>60
> strength["2016-10-17::"]
             RSI
2016-10-17  TRUE
2016-10-18  TRUE
2016-10-19  TRUE
2016-10-20 FALSE
2016-10-21 FALSE

> d["2016-10-17::"]
               Open
2016-10-17 642.2760
2016-10-18 640.5988
2016-10-19 637.0000
2016-10-20 631.9800
2016-10-21 633.6470

> d["2016-10-17::"][strength == TRUE]
Error in `[.xts`(d["2016-10-17::"], strength == TRUE) : 
  'i' or 'j' out of range
```

This is not the output I expect because both my objects have data until  2016-10-21. What could be wrong? I would like something like :

```
> d["2016-10-17::"][strength == TRUE]
               Open
2016-10-17 642.2760
2016-10-18 640.5988
2016-10-19 637.0000
```

This is the `str` of my xts objects :

```
> str(d)
An ‘xts’ object on 2013-09-02/2016-10-21 containing:
  Data: num [1:1146, 1] 127 128 121 121 116 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "Open"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ dateFormat: chr "Date"
 $ na.action :Class 'omit'  atomic [1:92] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "index")= num [1:92] 1.37e+09 1.37e+09 1.37e+09 1.37e+09 1.37e+09 ...

> str(strength)
An ‘xts’ object on 2013-09-16/2016-10-21 containing:
  Data: logi [1:1132, 1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "RSI"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
>
```

Thank you

Comment: There is a typo:  I believe`d["2016-10-17::"])[strength == TRUE]` should be `d["2016-10-17::"][strength == TRUE]`

Comment: Sorry this is a typo mistake in the Question statement. Corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't make a reproducible example, so here is some toy data.  Your issue is that you did not subset strength with the same time window (so your inner `strength == TRUE` logical series has different row length to your `d` row length, generating your error.  i.e. `NROW(strength == TRUE)` >> `NROW(d["2016-10-17::"])` ):

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
d <- AAPL
strength <- RSI(Cl(d)) > 60
```

You shouldn't get an error if you do this:

```
d["2016-10-17::"][strength["2016-10-17::"] == TRUE]
```